# Join list of string with commas and new lines

Tags: java, string, java-stream

I need to join a list of strings with commas. But also I have a limit of line length.
For example list `I need to join a list of strings with commas` should become :
`I, need, to, join, a, \n list, of, strings, with, \n commas`.

I've already implemented a method for this:

```
private static String joinLabels(List<String> strings) {
    int rowLengthCounter = 0;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (String str : strings) {
        rowLengthCounter += str.length();
        if (rowLengthCounter > 40) {
            result.append("\n");
            rowLengthCounter = str.length();
        }
        result.append(str);
        result.append(", ");
    }
    return result.substring(0, result.lastIndexOf(", "));
}
```

And it works. But maybe simple method exists, like String.join to join strings with specified delimiter, or stream API. Thanks for help.

Comment: There is no simple method in the form of an existing Java SE class that will do this.  Doing it with `Stream` would be convoluted ... which defeats the purpose of using `Stream`.

Comment: Your implementation doesn’t count the characters of the separator, further, the limit 40 is far too large for your expected example output. That’s inconsistent. The expectation of the example could be fulfilled with `String.join(", ", strings).replaceAll("\\G(?=.{25}).{1,23}, ", "$0\n")`

Answer (score 1):

One could argue the need of a steam in this case. But another solution that wasn't given here will be to create a custom collector. A collector is a mutable reduction operation and will look almost like the your current for loop code.

```java
public class CustomStringJoiner implements Collector<String, StringBuffer, String> {

        private int rowLength = 0;
        private final String delimiter;
        private final int maxRowSize;
        private boolean first;

        public CustomStringJoiner(String delimiter, int maxRowSize) {
            this.delimiter = delimiter;
            this.maxRowSize = maxRowSize;
            first = true;
        }

        @Override
        public Supplier<StringBuffer> supplier() {
            return StringBuffer::new;
        }

        @Override
        public BiConsumer<StringBuffer, String> accumulator() {
            return this::add;
        }

        @Override
        public BinaryOperator<StringBuffer> combiner() {
            return this::combine;
        }

        @Override
        public Function<StringBuffer, String> finisher() {
            return StringBuffer::toString;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
            return Set.of();
        }

        private void add(StringBuffer b, String v) {
            rowLength += v.length();


            if (!first) {
                b.append(delimiter);
            } else {
                first = false;
            }

            if (rowLength > maxRowSize) {
                b.append("\n");
                rowLength = v.length();
            }
            b.append(v);
        }

        private StringBuffer combine(StringBuffer a, StringBuffer b) {
            if (a.lastIndexOf("\n") == a.length()) {
                a.append(b);
            } else {
                for (final var s : b.toString().split(delimiter)) {
                    add(a, s);
                }
            }
            return a;
        }
    }
```

You can see that the `add` method is the same as your for loop.

use it like this:

```java
final String result = Stream.of(values).collect(new CustomStringJoiner(", ", 10));
System.out.println(result);
```

This will output:

```
I, need, to, 
join, a, list, 
of, strings, 
with, commas
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use java 8's stream and collectors api to do like this,

```
private static String joinLables(List<String> lables) {
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    final Integer chunkSize = 3;
    final String DELIMITER = ",";
    return lables.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize)).values()
            .stream()
            .map(s -> String.join(DELIMITER, s))
            .reduce((a, b) -> a + "\n" + b)
            .get();
}
```

Comment: you should change couter.addAndGet(it.length()) in order for this to work as expected

Answer (score 0):

The code is quite complicated with streams but you can write it like that :

```
    public static String joinLabels2(final List<String> strings,) {
    final Optional<String> res = strings.stream()
            .map(s -> s + ", ")
            .reduce((s1, s2) ->
                    s1.contains("\n") && (s1 + s2).length() - StringUtils.lastIndexOf(s1, "\n") > 40
                    ||
                    !s1.contains("\n") && (s1 + s2).length() > 40
                    ?
                    s1 + s2 + "\n" : s1 + s2)
            .map(s -> s.substring(0, s.length() - 2));
    return res.get();
}
```

Test by changing the max length from "40" to "10" :

```
@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println(joinLabels2(Arrays.asList("I", "need", "to", "join", "a", "list", "of", "strings", "with", "commas")));
}
```

outputs :

```
I, need, to, 
join, a, list, 
of, strings, 
with, commas,
```

It would be great to write the reduce condition like that : `(s1+s2).length() > 40 ? ...` but after the first line break the condition would be always true because s1 contains the previous reduction.

NB: you need to fine tune that method if you want to compare the length without commas because I added them before the reduction but you didn't in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
private static final int maxLength = 15;
private static final List<String> strings = 
    Arrays.asList("I", "need", "to", "join", "a", "list", "of", "strings", "with", "commas");
```

I can see 2 ways. They both rely on the fact that you can calculate the length of the current line in the StringBuilder this way:

`int currentLineLength = sb.length() - sb.lastIndexOf("\n");`

**1: The Stream way**

- Add commas to each string except the last one
- try to add each token to the `StringBuilder`

  - If adding next token to the the current line in the StringBuilder is more than max, add line break
  - Add token

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

IntStream.range(0, strings.size())
         .mapToObj(i -> strings.get(i) + (i<strings.size()-1 ?  ", " : ""))
         .forEach(s -> addToStringBuilder(s, sb));

System.out.println(sb);


private void addToStringBuilder(String s, StringBuilder sb) {
    int currentLineLength = sb.length() - sb.lastIndexOf("\n");
    if (currentLineLength + s.length() > maxLength) {
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    sb.append(s);
}
```

**2: Or you can go the recursive way**

```
String result = concatenate(strings, new StringBuilder());
System.out.println(result);

private String concatenate(List<String> remainingTokens, StringBuilder sb) {
    if(remainingTokens.size() == 0) {
        return sb.toString();
    }
    String nextToken = remainingTokens.size() > 1
        ? remainingTokens.get(0) + ", "
        : remainingTokens.get(0);

    int currentLineLength = sb.length() - sb.lastIndexOf("\n");
    if (currentLineLength + nextToken.length() > maxLength) {
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    sb.append(nextToken);
    return concatenate(remainingTokens.subList(1, remainingTokens.size()), sb);
}
```

Both output:

```
I, need, to, 
join, a, 
list, of, 
strings, 
with, commas
```